# Failed to generate key pair on Samsung S20, S20+ and S20 Ultra for biometric auth

Tags: android, keystore, samsung-mobile, biometrics, android-biometric

We have an issue with Samsung S20, S20+ and S20 Ultra devices when trying to generate a keypair upon enrolling in fingerprint auth in my app. We are only seeing this issue on the new Samsung S20 family with the Exynos chipset (International model) NOT Snapdragon, but not on any other devices. I tested it with US spec Samsung S20+, but I can't get it to repro the issue.

This is the exception.

```
    Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: Failed to generate key pair
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeystoreKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:556)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:499)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:727)
    at com.x.biometricskit.provider.BioKeyGeneratorImpl.generateKeyPair(BioKeyGenerator.kt:70)
    ... 34 more
    Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Unsupported digest
    at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1539)
    ... 38 more
```

Here's the code snippet for the BioKeyGeneratorImpl.generateKeyPair.

```
fun generateKeyPair(keyStoreAlias: String): KeyPair? {

    val specBuilder: KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder =
                    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyStoreAlias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                        .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(ECGenParameterSpec(EC_KEY_SPEC))
                        .setDigests(
                            KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                            KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA384,
                            KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512
                        )
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                        .setIsStrongBoxBacked(true)
                        .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)

    val keyPairGenSpec = specBuilder.build()

    val keyPairGenerator =
        KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
            KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC,
            "AndroidKeyStore"
        )

    keyPairGenerator.initialize(keyPairGenSpec)

    return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed it to

**KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256**

```
setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
```

and it works.

Hope this will help someone out there.

Comment: Have you experienced the problem with other devices or hardware manufacturers? We are somewhat reluctant to remove SHA_512 here or to implement a workaround for each device in the future.